# How to stop sharing data across companies/legal entities for EcoResProductMaster Table?

Tags: dynamics-365-operations

I have to change the table(Retail media resource) data to company specific,  Is that any other way to stop sharing the data to other legal entities? Thanks in advance

Tried to change the property(SaveDataPerCompany) but it is not possible through extension.

Answer (score 0):

As it is noted in the question, the `SaveDataPerCompany` property of tables from sealed standard modules cannot be modified with an extension. This means that data of tables where this property is set to "No" will always be shared between all legal entities.

Instead of preventing the sharing, access to the data can be restricted.

- Either the security privileges can be removed from users that should not be able to access the data. This will prevent them from accessing any data of that table. See [Role-based security](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/fin-ops-core/dev-itpro/sysadmin/role-based-security) for more information.
- Or if only access to some of the data should be allowed, a data security policy can be implemented. See [Extensible data security policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/fin-ops-core/dev-itpro/sysadmin/extensible-data-security-policies) for more information.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Is that preventing the sharing data between legal entities possible with security policies? Please share if you have exact workaround to achieve this.